# Report Server Failed to send email due to SMTP configuration issue

Tags: sql, database, smtp, smtp-auth, reportserver

I need a little or medium help. I have a report server that stopped sending out emails. The reason it stopped sending is the SMTP configuration. The seerver is an 08r2. I tried to open SQL server reporting services, hoping i could just change the setting there, nope. When try to open the server name or rather find it it doesn't. I looked for another way, and found the config file. I tried to make change to the config file, to just update the inforamtion but didn't/doesn't work. I am able to edit the file and save it but when testing the error I am getting is say --"*Failure sending mail: The server rejected the sender address. The server response was: 530 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM [BL0PR05CA0020.namprd05.prod.outlook.com] Mail will not be resent.*"-- So I tried a few other changes, different port 25 or 587, different email account. I tested in powershell with the accounts before try in the config file. In powershell I can get the emails to work so I know its not the accounts, its the config file and its setup.

I really only adjusted these items, before it had internal Smtp server IP, port 25, generic no-reply email for from and sendusing was set at 2.

- Smtp - smtp.office365.com
- port - 25 or 587 tried both
- smtpaccountname - using email address (data@mydomain.com)
- smtpusessl - tried 2 - think thats what is should be.
- sendingusessl - think should be 2
- smtpauthenticate - set to 2 also
- from - using email address (data@mydomain.com)

I based my changes also by reviewing https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/rsreportserver-config-configuration-file?view=sql-server-2014#bkmk_file_location  -- Extensions (RSReportServer.config file) Native Mode --

Here is the extract of the part that I changing and probably not doing correctly or missing something

<

```
Extension Name="Report Server Email" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.EmailDeliveryProvider.EmailProvider,ReportingServicesEmailDeliveryProvider">
                <MaxRetries>3</MaxRetries>
                <SecondsBeforeRetry>900</SecondsBeforeRetry>
                <Configuration>
                    <RSEmailDPConfiguration>
                        <SMTPServer>smtp.office365.com</SMTPServer>
                        <SMTPServerPort>25 or 587</SMTPServerPort>
                        <SMTPAccountName>EMail account to go here<SMTPAccountName>
                        </SMTPAccountName>Email account to go here<SMTPAccountName>
                        <SMTPConnectionTimeout>
                        </SMTPConnectionTimeout>
                        <SMTPServerPickupDirectory>
                        </SMTPServerPickupDirectory>
                        <SMTPUseSSL>? think it should be 2<SMTPUseSSL>
                        </SMTPUseSSL>
                        <SendUsing>? think it should be 2</SendUsing>
                        <SMTPAuthenticate>? think it should be 2<SMTPAuthenticate>
                        </SMTPAuthenticate>
                        <From>email from account</From>
                        <EmbeddedRenderFormats>
                            <RenderingExtension>MHTML</RenderingExtension>
                        </EmbeddedRenderFormats>
                        <PrivilegedUserRenderFormats>
                        </PrivilegedUserRenderFormats>
                        <ExcludedRenderFormats>
                            <RenderingExtension>HTMLOWC</RenderingExtension>
                            <RenderingExtension>NULL</RenderingExtension>
                            <RenderingExtension>RGDI</RenderingExtension>
                        </ExcludedRenderFormats>
                        <SendEmailToUserAlias>False</SendEmailToUserAlias>
                        <DefaultHostName></DefaultHostName>
                        <PermittedHosts>
                        </PermittedHosts>
                    </RSEmailDPConfiguration>
                </Configuration>
            </Extension>
```